# Cannot move all processes by a user into cgroup using cgred

Tags: centos7, systemd, cpu-usage, cgroup

I am on a CentOS 7.4 server, and trying to setup CGroups.

My cgconfig looks like this:

```
#
#  Copyright IBM Corporation. 2007
#
#  Authors: Balbir Singh <balbir@linux.vnet.ibm.com>
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of version 2.1 of the GNU Lesser General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it would be useful, but
#  WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
#
#
# By default, we expect systemd mounts everything on boot,
# so there is not much to do.
# See man cgconfig.conf for further details, how to create groups
# on system boot using this file.
#

mount {
    cpuset = /cgroup/cpuset;
}

group businesspro {
    cpu {
        cpu.shares="500";
    }
}

group startup {
    cpuset {
        cpuset.mems="0";
        cpuset.cpus="0";
    }
}
```

And cgrules.conf:

```
# /etc/cgrules.conf
#The format of this file is described in cgrules.conf(5)
#manual page.
#
# Example:
#<user>     <controllers>   <destination>
#@student   cpu,memory  usergroup/student/
#peter      cpu     test1/
#%      memory      test2/
# End of file
#
@watchdra   cpu     businesspro/
*:iscsid net_prio cgdcb-4-3260
dramafor    cpuset      cpuset:/startup/
```

Now what I am trying to do is move all the processes by `dramafor` into the cgroup `startup` with the `cpuset` controller. I've created that and restarted `cgred` and cgconfig `services` but the `startup/tasks` file is empty. I don't know how to even start debugging this. Can anyone either tell me what's going wrong, or at least tell me how to debug this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found out the answer. In my cgred, I had to do just `/startup` instead of `cpuset:/startup`

Simple syntax error for anyone with this same issue